# Why does my app crash when I pick a song from my music library in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mpmediaitem

My app crashes on this line of code and there is no error message printed in the console. Why does this happen? This is the line of code where it crashes.

```
let url: NSURL = (music.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!



func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

if isMediaPickerOne {
        isMediaPickerTwo = false
        let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem
        music = aMediaItem
        NSLog("\(aMediaItem.title)selected")

        //THIS LINE OF CODE IS WHERE IT CRASHES on the 6s and 6s plus. 
        let url: NSURL = (music.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL)!

        player =  AVPlayer(URL: url)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I had showCloudItems set to true and when I played a song from the cloud it crashed my app. I set it to false now everything works fine.